# JavaFX Native Bundle Splash Screen

Tags: maven, javafx, executable, splash-screen

I'm using the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) and *IntelliJ IDEA* on Windows 7.

I'm trying to get a splash screen to show while my JavaFX application boots up, like this:

[image]

I tried using the `SplashScreen-Image` manifest entry—and *that works*, but only if you click on the `.jar`—I'm deploying the application as a *Native Bundle* and so the user clicks an `.exe` (or a shortcut to an `.exe`) not the actual `.jar`.

*When you click the `.exe`  no splash screen is shown.*

---

[This SSCCE I made](https://github.com/TurekBot/Inno-Setup-SplashScreen-Test) will help *you* help *me*.

---

If I'm deploying my app using the [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin), (which, if I'm not mistaken, uses the *JavaFX Packager Tool*, which uses *[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php)*), how can I get a splash screen to show after the user clicks the `.exe`?

### More Findings:

- Looking at the installation directory, I find a .dll called `runtime\bin\splashscreen.dll`. Does that mean it can be done?

Comment: If you run the generated exe application right after build (not after installation), does it show the splash screen?

Comment: The executable `.jar` created right after the build *does* show the splash screen—there's no app-launching `.exe` until it's installed.

Answer (score 3):

The native launcher does not respect that spash-screen, it is only when being invoked by the java-executable. As the native launcher is loading the JVM internally, this won't work.

I haven't found a proper way to get this working, not even with some preloaders. Maybe you can find this helpful: https://gist.github.com/FibreFoX/294012b16fa10519674b (please ignore the deltaspike-related stuff)

Copied code:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // due to the nature of preloader being ignored within native-package, show it here
        SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplashScreen();
        splashScreen.show(new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT));

        // needed for callback
        final SomeJavaFXClassWithCDI launcherThread = this;

        // for splashscreen to be shown, its needed to delay everything else as parallel task/thread (it would block otherwise)
        Task cdiTask = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // boot CDI after javaFX-splash (this will "halt" the application due to the work done by CDI-provider
                bootCDI(launcherThread);

                // push javaFX-work to javaFX-thread
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    primaryStage.setTitle("Some Title");


                    // TODO prepare your stage here !


                    // smooth fade-out of slashscreen
                    splashScreen.fadeOut((ActionEvent event) -> {
                        primaryStage.show();
                        splashScreen.hide();
                    });
                });
                return null;
            }
        };

        // run task
        new Thread(cdiTask).start();
}
```

In short: I'm creating my splashscreen myself.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin

Comment: So passing the plugin JVM args using the `<jvmArgs>` tag works, but even if you pass it, the `-splash:` argument won't work?

Comment: I looked at the provided gist but am not sure where the SplashScreen class can be found. There's no apparent import or declaration shown.

Comment: Where can I find more info about the *native launcher*?

Comment: @BradTurek your should read the official documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html
the "native launcher" is the generated native binary (.exe-file on windows)